# Verb "contrive" in a context

Tags: phrase-meaning

Given such a sentence, would that verb "contrive" mean like, "set up"?

The "selected words 900 for TOEFL" gives synonyms of it as concoct, devise, fashion, improvise, invent.

> He **contrives/contrived** her death.

Definition from Merriam Unabridged.

> 1
>
> a :  devise, plan, plot
>
> contrive means of meeting
>
> b :  to fabricate as a work of art or ingenuity :  design, invent
>
> from stone, wood, shell, and bone the Indians contrived … household utensils —
>    American Guide Series: Tennessee
>
> 2
>
> now dialectal :  to find out :  understand
>
> 3
>
> obsolete :  to form, shape, lay out, or adapt by contrivance
>
> the whole shire contrived into 33 hundreds — John Speed
>
> 4
>
> :  to bring about by stratagem or with difficulty :  effect, manage — often followed by the infinitive

So only given such a sentence, can I deduct that the phrase would mean he "plotted" ( set up ) her death?

Comment: I am asking this question because of the word "death", which comes to me negatively.

Comment: What's your question exactly? What does *contrived* mean in *He contrived her death.*?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Would that make sense?

Comment: She didn't actually die. Her death was contrived (i.e. fabricated). It was made to appear as though she had died. That is another possible meaning. A contrivance can be a deception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in the context given, "arrange" or "set up" would equally express the general meaning, but they are not great synonyms because "contrive" includes a suggestion that the act is done in an irregular or improper manner. Notice that the list of suggested synonyms includes "concoct," "improvise," "devise," and "fashion," all of which suggest something that is not routine. "Contrive" may also suggest that the act is done in such a way that the actor's role remains secret as shown by "plot."

LATE EDIT: See JKreft's comment below. When plotting is suggested, it may involve any one or several aspects of the act contrived.

Comment: Followup to your last sentence, I'd add "or that it remain secret that the death was intentional."

Comment: JKreft. Thank you. You are correct that what is intended to be kept secret in a plot may not be the identity of the plotters though that is typically at least one of the aspects to be kept secret. I have added a brief edit.

Comment: I think that "plotting" somebody's death is a great example of a pun (unintentional or not).